Is my metamer paint combination problem equivalent to the minimum hitting set problem?
In trying to build a metamer system using paints, I'm running into a combinatorial optimization problem, and I want to map it to one of the classic NP-hard minimization problems. I have a number of paints, and I can combine paints into colors, with the goal of finding the smallest number of paints such that I can make every color.
More formally (with an example):
$P$: Set of paints $P = \{A, B, C, D\}$.
$C$: Set of colors $C = \{1, 2, 3\}$.
$M$: Set of combinations $M = \{M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5, M_6\}$.
Each combination $M_i \in M$ is a subset of paints $P$ that produces exactly one color from $C$. In my application, I am interested in combinations of 2 paints, but in general combinations can be one or many paints.
The goal is to find the smallest $P\prime \in P$ such all the combinations $M\prime$ covered by $P\prime$ hit every color in C.
\begin{align*}
M_1 & : \{A, B\} \rightarrow 1 \\
M_2 & : \{A, C\} \rightarrow 1 \\
M_3 & : \{A, D\} \rightarrow 2 \\
M_4 & : \{B, C\} \rightarrow 3 \\
M_5 & : \{B, D\} \rightarrow 3 \\
M_6 & : \{C, D\} \rightarrow 3 \\
\end{align*}
There are a number of minimum paint sets, but one might be ${A,C,D}$. In my real problem, I have ~500 paints and easily 1k+ colors. A greedy solution (with an approximation ratio) is good enough.
A friend of mine mentioned offhandedly that this is equivalent to the hitting set or set cover problem, but I'm having trouble formalizing the mapping. I know the colors would be the "universe", and the paints are the "elements", but the combination of elements don't exactly map to the "family of subsets" in the universe. Is this an accurate mapping? Is there another classical problem for which my problem is a straightforward match?
Edit: Marked this as duplicate to Prepare all dishes with the least different ingredients - what is this problem called?. The main difference between our formulations is that in my problem colors can be created by a varying number of combinations, and in the dishes optimization problem each dish has a fixed number of recipes. The integer linear programming solution still stands.

What operations can you perform?  I'm assuming you can enter a set of paints and see what color you get.  Can you enter a color and see what paint sets cause it?  Or anything else?

Not sure it has a name.  The correspondence between your problem and the duplicate is: paints<->ingredients, colors<->dishes, combinations<->recipes.  You can replace $k$ with $k_d$ to account for the number of recipes varying by dish.
